# Show Exception Errors in UI Firebase Auth Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

First of all i am new to Flutter, i read lots of threads but not getting anything.

**WHAT IS MY PROBLEM?**

i have two pages **auth.dart** and **login.dart**.In **auth.dart** page i have a class called **AuthService** which consists of the following code(to the point):

```
class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<bool> signInWithPhone(String phone, BuildContext context) async {
  ....
      verificationFailed: (AuthException exception) {
        // i can see the exception in debug console using print
        return exception;
      },
  ....
  }

}
```

In **login.dart**, i have a statefull widget which which looks like this and in there i referenced the above class and i am calling the **signInWithPhone** method:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {

  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  ....
  ....
  Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: FlatButton(
        child: Text("LOGIN"),
        textColor: Colors.white,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        onPressed: () {
            // here i am calling the method signInWithPhone of above class

            final phone = _phoneController.text.trim();
            _auth.signInWithPhone(phone, context);

        }
    )
  )
 ....
 ....
}
```

**WHAT I WANT?**

I want to display the exception error message received in onPressed event of my Login button so that i can display a alert dialogue using the error message.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED ?**

1) `print(_auth.signInWithPhone(phone, context));` But it returns null;

2)

```
_auth.signInWithPhone(phone, context).then((value){
   // alert/text/print
   print(value);
   }
```

this also returns null

Can anybody please help me solve it as i need to show user the error message if the mobile number is not correct or the OTP is not corrrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, first of all you need to listen to the exception and await it , you can return false in case of an expection and do something depending on that case like so.

you can return a map that contains the result and a message like so

```
{
  'message': message,
  'success' : true or false depending on the state of the request
}
```

**so**

in `AuthService.dart`

```dart
 verificationFailed: (AuthException exception) {
        // i can see the exception in debug console using print
        //return exception;
        return {
            'message': exception,
           'success': false
         }; // means verification failed;
 },
```

in `LoginScreen.dart`

```dart
void showAlert(message) {
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
       return AlertDialog(
         title: message,
       );
    });
}

 onPressed: async () {
            // here i am calling the method signInWithPhone of above class

            final phone = _phoneController.text.trim();
            final result = await _auth.signInWithPhone(phone, context);


            if(!result['suceess']) {
                 this.showAlert(result['message']);
             }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer it works But there is another thing if i want to show the error message of the verificationFailed method instead of showing My Hardcoded Errors in LoginScreen? is there any possibility to do so?

Comment: @MR_AMDEV i updated my answer to reflect the changed that you want

Comment: its giving me the following error `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'bool'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.dart(undefined_operator)`

Comment: oh, you need to update your method signature from `Future<bool> signInWithPhone` to 
`Future<Map> signInWithPhone`

Comment: I have changed it but now at runtime it gives me the following error:`Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("success"))`

Comment: you need to return a map in case of the request succeceed two, like when the request has been successfull you need to return something like this `return {'message': "success", "success": true};`

Comment: i got what you are saying but when i click the login button i am receiving the following error `Exception has occurred. NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []("success"))`

Comment: what i have seen so far is that from verificationFailed the return of {} map is returning as null in LoginClass

Comment: i have got it and the thing is inside a future function if there are callbacks then its not possible to return from those callbacks to the future function But we can get return value(either it is a map) from the FUTURE FUNCTION.Although, i have managed to show it by the help of try block and alert.